# How to use dependency injection in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, dependency-injection, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

I have an Eclipse plugin editor (now running on Kepler), and I want to use dependency injection to get contexts such as workbench, logger, etc'. My purpose is to make my code "more testable".

1. What plugin dependencies should I add to use the new DI?
2. Are there goo examples on how to use it?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are mainly interested in the dependency mechanisms of the Eclipse 4 workbench. I recommend these tutorials and articles for an introduction:

- an [Eclipse wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection) describing how this was introduced in Eclipse
- a great [tutorial](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/eclipse-4-e4-tutorial-part-4-dependency-injection-basics/) introducing the basics of this
  mechanism and how to use it in your plugin
- and of course a [huge tutorial on vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#d195409e2828) about all things E4 development, where dependency injection starts at chapter 23.